# Block Withholding Attacks

Tags: baking, protocol, proof-of-stake

Would it be possible to do something similar to selfish mining or rather a block withholding attack in Tezos and if so how would that work? As far as I understand, Tezos being a PoS system, it'll be hard to pull off such a thing due to the requirements of endorsements which decide the canonical chain and help in countering the Nothing-at-Stake problem.

Unless there is some sort of Cartel formation which with the right opportunity in baking slots and endorsement slots would allow such an attack to be possible.